# Controlling ggplot linewidth by variable value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that is 687 obs of 4 variables related to COVID-19 testing.

```
head(k)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  TestRate PosRate location  length
     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1    0.561   0.768 Australia    134
2    0.828   1.80  Australia    134
3    1.17    1.91  Australia    134
4    1.19    1.90  Australia    134
5    1.22    1.88  Australia    134
6    1.25    1.86  Australia    134
```

This represents the cumulative % of the population tested (TestRate) and the percent of tests returning positive (PosRate) for various countries (location).  length represents the number of days since that country's first positive test.

With this I can produce the following plot

```
g <- k %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=TestRate, y=PosRate)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=location), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = Endpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21,
             aes(color = location,fill = location), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(data=Endpoints, aes(label=location), show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Cumulative % of Population Tested",
       y = "% of Tests Returning Positive") +
       #title = "Test Positivity Rate (pop > 2,000,000 & > 0.75% pop tested)",
       #subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(COVtests$Date), "%A, %B %e, %Y")),
       #caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n
       #Data: Our World in Data (https://covid.ourworldindata.org)\n
       #UN Population Data (https://population.un.org)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1), lineheight = 0.5))

print(g)
```

[image]

which I think is fairly informative as it allows you to compare "trajectories" for different countries.  I have been asked to somehow include the information about the time since the first case in this plot though.  I have seen this done by animating the line draw, but a) I don't know how to do that and b) they like to distribute things as pdfs, so animated charts don't work well.

I had thought about trying to use the length value to control the line size by changing the code to

```
geom_line(aes(color=location, size=length), show.legend = FALSE) +
```

but then I wind up with a chart that looks like

[image]

This happens even if I "normalize" the length variable so that the values all lie between 0 and 1.

Is there any way to gain "fine" control over the line width in accordance with the value of a variable?  I'm not sure that would work visually, but at least I could show it to them....

Comment: You can gain fine control of line width adding `scale_size_manual(values=seq(1, 3,length.out=n)) `, where `n` is the number of countries.

Comment: forgive my ignorance....how would this tie the line width to the value of length?  could I c() together the lengths and pass that to scale_size_manual?

Comment: To connect line widths to values of `length` it is correct to use `+ geom_line(aes(color=location, size=length), show.legend = FALSE)`, but if you want to draw lines with sizes inside a specified range (say from 1 to 3), you can add `+ scale_size_manual(values=seq(1, 3,length.out=n))`

Comment: Understood, thanks! If you'd like to submit that as an answer...I'll also be posting a follow up question to a new post about how to animate this, just for my own edification.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider taking a ratio of positive tests to population tested and plot it relative to time? 
Or paste the time in days in the data label.
It is a graphically simple solution

Comment: I proposed just putting the number in the label...will see what they say